# Reference Request: Smooth Arzela-Ascoli Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces

I am using this result usually tied to the Arzela-Ascoli theorem:

> Let F be a subset of C(X) where X is a convex set in $R^n$ . Suppose that
>   each function in F is differentiable and there is a uniform bound on the partial derivatives
>   of these functions in F. Then F is equicontinuous.

But I cannot find a reference which I can cite for my project...would anyone know where I can find this in a book or paper?  Every version I find is either more general or less than this exact version...

Comment: I would expect to see this as an exercise in a real analysis book if anywhere...it is a quite straightforward application of the mean value theorem or FTC.

Comment: I know it is straightforward but I don't want to the limited space I'm allowed for my project length... I honestly couldn;t find it in the analysis texts i have

Comment: Perhaps you can provide an expected level of details needed for your project, for otherwise you can simply mention the keyword 'uniform Lipschitz condition' to satisfy any accustomed readers.

Comment: possibly....... but id rather a reference

Comment: You assume only convexity of $X$? It is not open?

Comment: Yes, is this odd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This result is not any kind of Arzela-Ascoli theorem (which is a statement about compactness). Rather, it is a form of the Mean Value Theorem, or perhaps Mean Value Inequality (since the relation $f(a)-f(b) = f'(c)(a-b)$ becomes an inequality in higher dimensions):
$$
|f(a)-f(b)|\le \sup_\Omega \|\nabla u\| \ \|a-b\|
$$
where $\Omega$ is a convex set containing $a, b$.

It can be found in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (Theorem 9.19, page 218 of the 3rd edition), and I'd expect it to be in good multivariable calculus textbooks like Apostol's.

Comment: Perfect, do you know the chapter?  I guess in a chapter on MVT or something?  Also, I was using it to setup the equicontinuity for arzela-ascoli

Comment: (Theorem 9.19, page 218 of the 3rd edition)